# How to create a Date variable in Elm

Tags: elm

I want to hardcode a date in a record in elm. The record signature is

```
type alias Record = { .., startDate : Date, .. }
```

On my code I am doing

```
record = { .., startDate = Date.fromString "2011/1/1", .. }
```

The problem is that the Record type expects a **Date** type but **Date.fromString** signature is

```
String -> Result.Result String Date.Date
```

How can I create the **Date** to use on the **Record** type?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're getting the `Result` because there is a chance that parsing the string to a date failed. You can handle it one of 2 ways.

#### Ignore it

If you want to just say "I know this string will be valid date and I'm not worried that I may have messed it up" then you can just provide a default date

```elm
Date.fromString "2011/1/1" |> Result.withDefault (Date.fromTime 0)
```

This will leave you with a `Date` but will default to the unix epoch if the parse fails.

#### Use it

Think about what you would want to happen if the parse *were* to fail and handle it where the date is used. Ex. if you're displaying it as a string you could display the date or if the parse failed display `"TBA"`.

**Note**: You may have noticed that `Date.fromTime` just returns a `Date` not a `Result` (because an `Int` can *always* be parsed to a `Date`). If you don't mind converting your dates to unix timestamps you could hardcode the timestamp and use that without having to deal with `Result`s

Comment: In repl , `Date.fromString "2011/1/1" |> Result.withDefault (Date.fromTime 0)` return : `{} : Date.Date`. Still no date...

Comment: The `Date.Date` type just doesn't `toString` well and shows up as `{}`. If you try `(Date.fromString "2011/1/1" |> Result.withDefault (Date.fromTime 0) |> (\d -> (Date.year d, Date.month d, Date.day d)))` you should see `(2011,Jan,1) : ( Int, Date.Month, Int )`